# Cannot 'pickle' a Tkinter object in a multiprocessing environment in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to create an application where a Tkinter GUI is updated by other objects that are continuously taking data. I was having issues using multithreading so I decided to try and use the multiprocessing module.

I've found that you cannot run a Tkinter window inside of a `multiprocessing.Process`, here is the minimum example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing

class Subprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
    #

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
    #

    def stop(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        self.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        process = Subprocess()
        process.start()
        print "I got around the global interpreter lock"
        raw_input()
        print "exiting"
        process.stop()
```

What I expect to happen is for a Tk window to pop up and "I got around the global interpreter lock" to show up in the terminal. I tested this out on ubuntu linux and it worked fine, but when I switched over to Windows 7 (where I am developing my application) it failed giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pathtoscript\multiprocessing_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    process.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
PicklingError: Can't pickle 'tkapp' object: <tkapp object at 0x02BD3D08>
```

Does anyone know a workaround to this? It seems odd to me that this works on linux but not on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix - Just create the `tkapp` object in the child process, rather than the parent:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing
from Queue import Empty

class Subprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.after(100, self._check_queue) # Check the queue every 100ms
        self.root.mainloop()

    def _check_queue(self):
        try:
            out = self.queue.get_nowait()
            if out == 'stop':
                self.do_stop()
                return
            # Could check for other commands here, too
        except Empty:
            pass
        self.root.after(100, self._check_queue)

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put('stop')

    def do_stop(self):
        self.root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = Subprocess()
    process.start()
    print "I got around the global interpreter lock"
    raw_input()
    print "exiting"
    process.stop()
```

Trying to create the `tkapp` in the parent, but then start in the child, isn't going to be a workable solution. The only tricky part is that you need to use a `Queue` to tell the loop in the child process to stop from the parent.

Also, for what its worth, running the original code on Linux actually crashes the interpreter for me:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 87 requests (87 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

Comment: There is an issue for the code as you have written it, when it closes, i.e. when process.stop() gets called it throws an error: "AttributeError: 'Subprocess' object has no attribute 'root' " which is odd because the self.root attribute was set in the run function

Comment: @trvrrp Fixed now. Sorry, I missed the call to `stop` initially. You can't access `root` from the parent, because the attribute only exists in the child process. You have to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to tell the child to terminate the mainloop instead.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a target function into that subprocess? If it could handle arguments and return would be even better.